# need help searching for multiple properties in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm doing a Query for a certain user in AD and looking to create a list of multiple properties. Code Below. When I do searchResult.Properties["manager"] or searchResult.Properties["mail"] i get the correct result each way. But how would i search for multiple properties?

```
DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path);    

                DirectorySearcher dSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);                    

                dSearcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=user)(samaccountname=mcavanaugh))";    

                sResults = dSearcher.FindAll();

                foreach (SearchResult searchResult in sResults)
                {
                    var sAMAccountName = searchResult.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString().ToLower();
                    if (sAMAccountName == "mcavanaugh")
                    {
                        //Right here is where i would select multiple ad properties
                        ResultPropertyValueCollection valueCollection = searchResult.Properties["manager, mail"];

                        foreach (Object propertyValue in valueCollection)
                        {
                            var PropertyName = (string)propertyValue.ToString();
                            testlist.Text = PropertyName;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Properties` property doesn't have an option to access multiple properties at once. Mixing the values from different properties doesn't seem wise. Your best solution is to run the `foreach` twice, possibly creating a function to be DRY.

```
void addPropertyValues<T>(SearchResult sr, T testlist, string propName) {
    foreach (var pv in sr[propName]) {
        testlist.Text = pv.ToString();
    }
}
```

which you can use in your `if`

```
if (sAMAccountName == "mcavanaugh") {
    addPropertyValues(searchResult, testlist, "manager");
    addPropertyValues(searchResult, testlist, "mail");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with this lately.  I found where to place multiple properties and put them into an array, assigning them to properties.  It's been working out pretty well so far. :

```
DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=demo,DC=Com");

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection);
search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + username + ")";

string[] requiredProperties = new string[] { "cn", "Displayname", "Title", "Department", "l", "Homedirectory", "telephoneNumber", "lockoutTime", "badlogoncount", "passwordexpired", "badPasswordTime", "whenCreated", "sAMAccountName", "pwdLastSet", "thumbnailPhoto", "givenName", "sn", "mail", "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress", "distinguishedName", "manager" };


foreach(String property in requiredProperties)
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);

//next code will output to a usertextbox that I had set up in a Form. You can convert to console.writeline

if (searchResult != null) {
    foreach(String property in requiredProperties)
    foreach(Object myCollection in searchResult.Properties[property])
    UserTextbox.Text += "\r\n" + (String.Format("{0,0} : {1} : {2}", property, myCollection.ToString(), myCollection.GetType().ToString()));
}
```